# Starter issue with 98 Mercedes ML320

Tags: starter, mercedes-benz, ml320

The starter on my daughter's ML320 stopped working. We ordered a new one and replaced it. However, the car is still not starting. We can hear the relay clicking, the fuel pump running, and the solenoid in the starter is throwing. But it's still not cranking.

I took off the new starter and had it tested at the local Autozone, as well as the battery. Both passed fine.

What else am I missing? What else could I check without having to have this towed to the local MB dealership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A corroded ground would prevent the starter from drawing enough current.

Comment: Replaced the battery cable between battery and alternator and alternator and starter.